# how to add data to pane dynamically in java fx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-3d

im working on javafx project and im stuck in this problem i want to show data from my db and each data i want to show it in a different Pane so i have to loop through my data 
 this is my code

```
   @FXML
private Pane pane;

@FXML
private Label lblusername;

@FXML
private Label lbldescription;
/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


          IPublicationService ps = new PublicationService();
          IMembreService ms = new MembreService();
          List<Publication> lp = ps.getAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < lp.size(); i++) {
            // lp.get(i).getCreateur().getId() retourne id dde user
            // getuser retroune un objet user
        lblusername = new Label(ms.getUser(lp.get(i).getCreateur().getId()).getUsername()); 
        lbldescription = new Label(lp.get(i).getDescription()); 
        pane = new Pane();
        pane.setLayoutX(14.0);
                    pane.setLayoutY(137.0);
                    pane.setPrefHeight(200.0);
                   pane.setPrefWidth(705.0);
                    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: darkgrey");

        pane.getChildren().addAll(lblusername,lbldescription);

    }
```

but when i run my project i got nothing this is my output 
[image]

Comment: `pane` is the container that you want to use to hold all the items. But you are recreating this `Pane` in every iteration step: `pane = new Pane();`, so the original one remains empty. I would propose to modify the FXML file and have e.g. a `VBox` as root. And then in every iteration step create a new `Pane` like `Pane pane = new Pane();` and then add this `Pane` to the `VBox`: `vbox.getChildren.add(pane);`.

Comment: how the original pane stay empty i changed it in every iteration with adding items to it ?

Comment: i didnt understand you could you help me with some piece of code

Comment: The original `Pane` is inserted by the FXMLLoader, that `Pane` is displayed on the GUI, and variable `pane` is a pointer to this `Pane`. When you call `pane = new Pane();` you modify this pointer to a new `Pane` which is not part of the scene-graph (not presented on the GUI), but the original one still remains there, and remains empty.

Comment: thnks a lot you save me